Algebraic groups and formal group laws in characteristic p
In characteristic zero, there is a well-known equivalence between Lie groups, formal group laws and Lie algebras.
Let $p$ be a prime. The equivalence between Lie groups and Lie algebras has an analogue in characteristic $p$, namely the Lazard correspondence between $p$-groups of nilpotency class $<p$ and $p$-Lie rings of nilpotency class $<p$ (we can even replace the nilpotency class condition by a condition of every $3$-generated subgroup) where the group law is defined from the Lie bracket (and conversely) via the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff (BCH) formula (resp. by  its inverse). In particular, such a $p$-group always "extends to" (i.e. is the group of $\mathbb{F}_p$-points of) an algebraic group over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (consider the corresponding $p$-Lie ring $L$ and define the algebraic group whose functor of points maps a ring $R$ of characteristic $p$ to the group $G(R)$ obtained by equipping the Lie ring $L \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} R$ with the BCH-law).
That algebraic group, moreover, satisfies  the following form of "Hilbert 90": for any field $K$ of characteristic $p$, the set of nonabelian group cohomology $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K^{\text{sep}}|K), G(K^{\text{sep}}))$ is a singleton, as we show by induction on the nilpotency class, the abelian case following from $H^1(\mathrm{Gal}(K^{\text{sep}}|K), K^{\text{sep}})=1$.
I am interested in knowing what can be said without the nilpotency class restriction. Obviously, the BCH-law makes no sense as there may be nonzero commutators whose coefficients have a $p$ in their denominator.
A good candidate for an "algebraic" analogue of Lie groups in characteristic $p$ is given by algebraic groups over $\mathbb{F}_p$.
However, to any algebraic group $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$ (of identity element $e$), we can associate a "formal group law", namely the morphism of local rings $\mathcal{O}_{G,e} \to \mathcal{O}_{G,e} \otimes \mathcal{O}_{G,e}$ induced by the multiplication morphism $G \times G \to G$ (we could take completions relative to the maximal ideals to obtain power series, making this even more similar to formal group laws, but this is somewhat artificial in this algebraic setting).
So we recover, very generally and without nilpotency class restriction, one of the functors in the correspondence, namely the functor from algebraic groups to "formal group laws" (which I think are just Hopf algebras whose underlying ring is a commutative local ring)
I am interested in knowing if (maybe by adding some restrictions) we get a pseudo-inverse to that functor. Or if there is some well-known geometric "Lie correspondence" for algebraic groups over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Maybe something more precise can be said by restricting to algebraic groups satisfying the "Hilbert 90" property above. Any reference to these topics, and even any treatment of the above functor would be of interest to me.
